# Displaying XML attributes in PHP

Tags: python, php, xml

I am a beginner in coding and have this question below. I would gladly appreciate any help.

I have this python code below that request for information regarding a organization.

Note: The Commented "target" variable is for future use when i pass the user input from php to this python script.

```
import requests, sys
#target = sys.argv[1]
target = "logitech"


request = requests.get('http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;name={}'.format(target))


print(request.text)
```

The output is similar to this but the number of "netRef" tags may vary depending on the organization.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://whois.arin.net/xsl/website.xsl' ?><nets xmlns="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/rdns/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/netref/v2" copyrightNotice="Copyright 1997-2020, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd." inaccuracyReportUrl="https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/" termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/"><limitExceeded limit="256">false</limitExceeded>
<netRef endAddress="173.8.217.111" startAddress="173.8.217.96" handle="NET-173-8-217-96-1" name="LOGITECH">https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-173-8-217-96-1</netRef>
<netRef endAddress="50.193.49.47" startAddress="50.193.49.32" handle="NET-50-193-49-32-1" name="LOGITECH">https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-50-193-49-32-1</netRef></nets>
```

I was wondering, is it possible to only display all of the endAddress and startAddress attributes in PHP?

I've tried using the xml.etree.ElementTree module but because the request variable is a "response" instead of a "byte", i can't parse the XML directly into an element.

My PHP code currently looks like this as i am unsure of how to proceed. testapi.py refers to the python code above.

```
<?php

$output1 = shell_exec('python testapi.py');

echo $output1;
?>
```

My desired output on the PHP side is as follow:

```
IP range: 173.8.217.96-173.8.217.111, 50.193.49.32-50.193.49.47
```

I would gladly appreciate any help, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `etree` maintains the [**`fromstring`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) method to parse XML trees from text. From there, you can parse content and be sure to assign prefixes to the default namespace in XML:

`xmlns="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1"`

```
import requests as rq
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

request = rq.get('http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;name=logitech')

tree = ET.fromstring(request.text)

nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1"}
for elem in tree.findall(".//doc:netRef", nmsp):
    print(f"endAddress: {elem.attrib['endAddress']}")
    print(f"startAddress: {elem.attrib['startAddress']}")
    print("---------------------------\n")

# endAddress: 173.8.217.111
# startAddress: 173.8.217.96
# ---------------------------

# endAddress: 50.193.49.47
# startAddress: 50.193.49.32
# ---------------------------
```

Comment: OMG Thank You so much. But, so sorry to trouble you again, would you mind explaining to me what this portion of the code does? Greatly appreciated.


nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1"}
for elem in tree.findall(".//doc:netRef", nmsp):

Comment: As I mention in text, your XML has a [default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting). So in order to retrieve underlying values, you need to assign a temporary prefix which can be anything. Here I used `doc` (but can be assigned anything like `wasd`) but must be used to parse unprefixed elements like `<netRef>`: `.//doc:netRef`.  The second argument of [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) is for *namespaces*.